# Xml Tree Bottom Up algorithm, Performances: XmlTextReader vs XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, performance

I know that XmlTextReader is a lot faster than using XDocument to read an XML file, but I will need to generate a tree object any way when reading the XmlTextReader because I need to execute an algorithm on the tree that requires the node to be ordered by button up.

Performance is at the utmost importance for this script, so I where wondering will it still be faster for me to use XmlTextReader and generating my own tree, then using XDocument, which I guess is highly optimized. Memory is not a problem, the only problem is run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a Little test to see the diffrence, in my test i generate a random XML tree of random depth, and then test the time of "simply reading the file line by line", XDocument and XmlDocument and the following is the result. Please note that the data should be take with a gram of salt as background program might have taken more CPU time at one point then another but i have tries to minimized it.

```
Generating XML file of size 100000 nodes.
Random Tree Generate time: 00:00:00.1450100
Basic read (100000 nodes): 00:00:00.0340026
XDocument (100000 nodes): 00:00:00.0970074
XmlDocument (100000 nodes): 00:00:00.1310083


Generating XML file of size 200000 nodes.
Random Tree Generate time: 00:00:00.2800201
Basic read (200000 nodes): 00:00:00.0720057
XDocument (200000 nodes): 00:00:00.2140145
XmlDocument (200000 nodes): 00:00:00.3780260


Generating XML file of size 300000 nodes.
Random Tree Generate time: 00:00:00.4320307
Basic read (300000 nodes): 00:00:00.1170083
XDocument (300000 nodes): 00:00:00.3940275
XmlDocument (300000 nodes): 00:00:00.6610466


Generating XML file of size 400000 nodes.
Random Tree Generate time: 00:00:00.4920347
Basic read (400000 nodes): 00:00:00.1280360
XDocument (400000 nodes): 00:00:00.5806501
XmlDocument (400000 nodes): 00:00:00.5740402


Generating XML file of size 1000000 nodes.
Random Tree Generate time: 00:00:01.2270864
Basic read (1000000 nodes): 00:00:00.2940205
XDocument (1000000 nodes): 00:00:01.5451096
XmlDocument (1000000 nodes): 00:00:02.0201415


Generating XML file of size 2000000 nodes.
Random Tree Generate time: 00:00:02.5251779
Basic read (2000000 nodes): 00:00:00.6170434
XDocument (2000000 nodes): 00:00:03.4573680
XmlDocument (2000000 nodes): 00:00:03.3052323


Generating XML file of size 3000000 nodes.
Random Tree Generate time: 00:00:03.5962528
Basic read (3000000 nodes): 00:00:00.9170651
XDocument (3000000 nodes): 00:00:05.1344993
XmlDocument (3000000 nodes): 00:00:05.4273814


Generating XML file of size 4000000 nodes.
Random Tree Generate time: 00:00:04.4403129
Basic read (4000000 nodes): 00:00:01.3062051
XDocument (4000000 nodes): 00:00:07.0914985
XmlDocument (4000000 nodes): 00:00:07.1036703


Generating XML file of size 5000000 nodes.
Random Tree Generate time: 00:00:05.6483977
Basic read (5000000 nodes): 00:00:01.6771169
XDocument (5000000 nodes): 00:00:09.0457656
XmlDocument (5000000 nodes): 00:00:08.9917587


Generating XML file of size 6000000 nodes.
Random Tree Generate time: 00:00:07.2595102
Basic read (6000000 nodes): 00:00:01.9852661
XDocument (6000000 nodes): 00:00:10.6767517
XmlDocument (6000000 nodes): 00:00:12.0809750


Generating XML file of size 7000000 nodes.
Random Tree Generate time: 00:00:07.5056502
Basic read (7000000 nodes): 00:00:02.3651666
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument failed at 7000000 nodes
XmlDocument (7000000 nodes): 00:00:12.8675950


Generating XML file of size 8000000 nodes.
Random Tree Generate time: 00:00:09.0982253
Basic read (8000000 nodes): 00:00:02.6701876
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument failed at 8000000 nodes
XmlDocument (8000000 nodes): 00:00:16.7583049


Generating XML file of size 9000000 nodes.
Random Tree Generate time: 00:00:10.0358261
Basic read (9000000 nodes): 00:00:03.0752163
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument failed at 9000000 nodes
XmlDocument (9000000 nodes): 00:00:17.4173450


Generating XML file of size 10000000 nodes.
Random Tree Generate time: 00:00:10.9155418
Basic read (10000000 nodes): 00:00:03.8667958
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument failed at 10000000 nodes
XmlDocument (10000000 nodes): 00:00:18.1173983
```

Here is my test code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
        {

            int nodeSize;
            if (i < 5)
            {
                nodeSize = 100000*i;
            }
            else
            {
                nodeSize = 1000000 * (i-4);
            }
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nGenerating XML file of size " + nodeSize + " nodes.");
                DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
                Random rand = new Random();
                string path = @"C:\Users\b-kass\Documents\Projects\XmlDiff\Large.xml";
                using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(path, false))
                {
                    outfile.Write("<root>\n");
                    int maxNodes = nodeSize;
                    while (maxNodes > 0)
                    {
                        maxNodes -= writeXml(outfile, rand, maxNodes);
                    }
                    outfile.Write("</root>\n");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Random Tree Generate time: " + (DateTime.Now - start));

            try
            {
                start = DateTime.Now;
                // Read the file and display it line by line.
                using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path))
                {
                    while (file.ReadLine() != null)
                    {
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Basic read (" + nodeSize + " nodes): " + (DateTime.Now - start));

            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Basic read failed at " + nodeSize + " nodes");
            }

                try
                {
                    start = DateTime.Now;
                    var xd = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(path);
                    Console.WriteLine("XDocument (" + nodeSize + " nodes): " + (DateTime.Now - start));
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("System.Xml.Linq.XDocument failed at " + nodeSize + " nodes");
                }


                try
                {
                    start = DateTime.Now;
                    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(path);
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.Load(reader);
                    reader.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("XmlDocument (" + nodeSize + " nodes): " + (DateTime.Now - start));
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("XmlDocument failed at " + nodeSize + " nodes");
                }

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int writeXml(StreamWriter outfile, Random rand, int maxNode)
    {
        int mymax = (int)Math.Ceiling(maxNode * rand.NextDouble());
        int count = mymax;
        while (mymax > 0)
        {
            string node = "node" + ((int) Math.Ceiling(15*rand.NextDouble()));
            outfile.Write("\n<" + node + ">");
            if (rand.NextDouble() > 0.5 && mymax > 1) // Have nodes?
            {
                mymax -= writeXml(outfile, rand, mymax);
            }
            else // have value
            {
                outfile.Write("Data random data " + rand.Next());
            }
            outfile.Write("</" + node + ">");
            mymax--;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```